# How to run yo generator command when the generator package is from VSTS registry

Tags: npm, yeoman, yeoman-generator, azure-artifacts

I published my generator-app to our team's VSTS npm registry, and i can install it into my local machine by using command: `npm install -g geneartor-app`, however when i run the yo command: `yo app`, it show bellow error:

```
E:\workspace
λ yo app
Error app

You don't seem to have a generator with the name “app” installed.
But help is on the way:

You can see available generators via npm search yeoman-generator or via http://yeoman.io/generators/.
Install them with npm install generator-app.

To see all your installed generators run yo without any arguments. Adding the --help option will also show subgenerators.

If yo cannot find the generator, run yo doctor to troubleshoot your system.
```

Does anyone know why yeoman cannot find the `generator-app` package. 
BTW, `npm link` can work and i generated the `generator-app` by using yeoman's generator-generator. Here's my source code:

[image]

Comment: What's `yo doctor` says? And do you have generator folder where your app located inside? More details, you can refer http://yeoman.io/authoring/index.html.

Comment: @MarinaLiu-MSFT `yo doctor` says "Everything looks all right!"

Comment: And what's your file structure? Can you share your project in one drive?

Comment: i generated it by using generator-generator.can i ping you?

Comment: Can you show the whole steps for how you create your app?

Comment: added the source code list.

Comment: it seems there has no such generator app (http://yeoman.io/generators/), can you check id the generator is available by `yo --generators` commmand.

Comment: Yes, i do not and cannot publish it to yeoman.io. I published it to my team's vsts npm registry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's my own problem that i forgot to modify the `files` option in package.json after removing the generators folder.